# How to tell the compiler to use hardware floating point instructions with ARM

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, arm

I am compiling a program for ARM. The makefile has a flag *-msoft-float* which is telling the compiler to use software floating point emulation. My question is how can I specify in the makefile to use the hardware floating point instructions instead. I tried *-mhard-float*, but if I do so I get errors. I also tried *-msoftfp-float* as told by [this site](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/ARM-Options.html) but the compiler doesn't even recognize that flag. So, please tell me how should I solve this problem.

Comment: Please confirm the compiler version and if you know where it came from (CodeSourcery, Linaro, Debian, Ubuntu, etc).

Comment: read about `-mfpu` at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html.

Answer (score 4):

Soft float is an option to configure **gcc**, it is open source and anyone can configure a tool chain with/without *soft float* support.  See http://crosstool-ng.org/ for a tool to build your own compiler.  I take it from the referenced link that *gcc 4.1.2* is being used; You will probably have the best luck with `-mfloat-abi=softfp`.  There are three variants on the ARM.  The [Debian ARM floating point wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort) does an excellent job of describing the differences. Also [Debian VFP comparison](http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort/VfpComparison) may be of interest.

Comment: More links: [Linaro](https://wiki.linaro.org/Linaro-arm-hardfloat), [Raspberry Pi Blog](http://www.memetic.org/raspbian-benchmarking-armel-vs-armhf/).  Also, your OS (or lack of) may have an influence on your options.  If neither `-mfloat-abi=softfp` or `-mfloat-abi=hard` work you will need a new compiler. If `-mfloat-abi=softfp` works, you will want to specify `-mfpu=XXX`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this site. It seems to do the trick

http://www.eliteraspberries.com/blog/2013/08/cflags-for-numerical-computing-on-the-raspberry-pi.html

Answer (score -1):

Try `gcc` option:

`-mno-soft-float`

Comment: It doesn't recognize this flag.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: That means your toolchain does not support it. this is not uncommon for free toolchains. Commercial ones often offers this.