# Using ARMv7 and ARM library in the same Android App

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, andengine, dropbox-api

I am struggling with using Dropbox (Sync API) and Andengine in the same android app. Both are using native libraries and, as far as I know, Andengine is developed for ARMv7a and Dropbox for ARM systems. Running each part of the application on its own, everything works fine. However, combining both parts results in a:  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load DropboxSync: findLibrary returned null.

It seems that only the **armeabi-v7a** folder is checked for the library as soon as this folder is present? However, the libDropboxSync.so is only located in the **armeabi** folder.

Everything is tested with a Nexus S running Android 4.1.2.

Thanks in advance,
Stefan

Comment: See [armeabi-v7a vs armeabi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080525/why-use-armeabi-v7a-code-over-armeabi-code).  You can not mix and match the two.  You have a **multi-lib** installation, so  need *dropbox* compiled from *v7a*.  It is possible to write **shims** allowing inter-operate.  I guess the Android loader is not supporting this.  The **shims** maybe highly in-efficient, storing floating point registers when it isn't needed, etc. Also, [harware floating point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998609/how-to-tell-the-compiler-to-use-hardware-floating-point-instructions-with-arm).

Answer (score 1):

From [$NDK/docs/CPU-ARCH-ABIS.html](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/CPU-ARCH-ABIS.html): if `primary-abi` is found `secondary` won't be scanned.

```
III.3. Automatic extraction of native code at install time:
-----------------------------------------------------------

When installing an application, the package manager service will scan
the .apk and look for any shared library of the form:

     lib/<primary-abi>/lib<name>.so

If one is found, then it is copied under $APPDIR/lib/lib<name>.so,
where $APPDIR corresponds to the application's specific data directory.

If none is found, and a secondary ABI is defined, the service will
then scan for shared libraries of the form:
```

You can check this by;

```
$ adb shell getprop|grep abi
[ro.product.cpu.abi2]: [armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [armeabi-v7a]
```

as you can see primary abi is more specific then the secondary one.

Solution-wise you can move armv5 library under armv7-a. It *should* work, but it will be only visible to such devices under `Google Play`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the 3rd and 4th point

> 1. Within Android Studio, switch to the "project view".
> 2. From the libs directory in the downloaded SDK, drag dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar into your project's app/libs directory.
> 3. Right-click on dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar and choose "Add as library". Click "OK" on the dialog that appears.
> 4. Make a new directory in your project under app/src/main called jniLibs. From the SDK, drag armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, and x86 into
>      the new jniLibs directory.